# iMacros using EVAL to extract

Tags: javascript, copy, extract, paste, imacros

I want to change it to make it work

```
code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT \n";
        code+=  'SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'; x;")' + "\n";
```

I want it like this

```
code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT \n";
        code+=  'SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'; x;")' + "\n";
if (var1)>10{`code+="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS\n";
}else{
code+="TAB OPEN\n";
}
```

Help me please
help me

Comment: Please take some time to read [this site's help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the pages ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```
// here your iimPlayCode(code); or iimPlay(code);
if (parseInt(iimGetExtract()) > 10)
    iimPlayCode("TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS");
else
    iimPlayCode("TAB OPEN");
```